# Agregar array en Firebase C#

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, hashmap

Necesito cada vez que presione un botón agregar un campo a un `array` de `Firestore-Firebase`.

El campo sera (para este ejemplo) el nombre de un cliente.

Entonces lo que tendría que quedar es algo así:

```
Proyecto A
{ 
Nombre: Proyecto Navidad
Clientes: { Juan, Pedro, Ismael }
}
```

He logrado actualizar el array, el problema con esto es que cada vez que presiono el botón en lugar de ir agregando mas clientes solo logro que me actualice (sustituye el cliente anterior por el nuevo, entonces siempre me deja solo 1 cliente, el ultimo cliente.) y no logro hacer que solo vaya agregando mas y mas.

Codigo C#:

```
DocumentReference docRef = database.Collection("Proyectos").Document(IdDoc);

                    HashMap mapMatrizClientes = new HashMap();

                    mapMatrizClientes.Put(AutoIdDoc, vClienteNuevo);

                    docRef.Update("Proyectos", mapMatrizClientes);
                    ShowToast("Cliente agregado");
```

Y al final lo que consigo es esto:

```
Proyecto A
    { 
    Nombre: Proyecto Navidad
    Clientes: { Juan }
    }
```

- 

```
Proyecto A
    { 
    Nombre: Proyecto Navidad
    Clientes: { Pedro }
    }
```

Comment: no entiendo lo de matriz, firebase solo deja arrays y objetos json.  Si es un array tienes el union, si es json puedes actualizar el campo como un objeto.

Comment: Si, me refiero al array. Intente con la palabra UNION pero no me la reconoce como una palabra reservada en el HashMap; serias tan amable de darme un ejemplo con una linea de codigo C#? Gracias de antemano

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=es#c_11

Comment: Elige c# en el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo.

Lo logre de la siguiente forma:

```
var batch = database.Batch();
    
                vUsuario = "Usuario";
                vFechaHora = Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow);

                var MapArray = new HashMap();
                MapArray.Put("Usuario", vUsuario);
                MapArray.Put("FechaHora", vFechaHora);

                var FSColeccion = database.Collection($"Coleccion/{vIdDoc}/ColeccionOpcional").Document();
                batch.Set(FSColeccion, MapArray);

                await batch.Commit();
```